Why is Tensorflow not Detecting My GPU despite installing cuDNN and CUDA?
Device Specifications:-



Column A
Column B




GPU
RTX 3060


OS
Windows 11


Tensorflow Version
2.17.0


Python Version
3.12.5



from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
def get_available_devices():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]
print(get_available_devices()) 

This is returning ['/device:CPU:0']
Here is all that I tried to no avail:-
Reference Material

Installed the required versions of cuDNN and CUDA (8.9 and 12.3 respectively).
Copied bin, lib and include folders over to C:.....\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\
Added the bin and libnvvp to system paths variable
Installed Visual Studio installer and installed Desktop Development with C++
Restarted

Here is all the troubleshooting I did

Ran nvcc --version, working....

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__8_19:56:38_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.52
Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33281558_0


Ran nvidia-smi - GPU is showing up
Ran tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') Returning Empty List

Nothing Seems to be Working, Please Help. Be kind and Thank You.

Seems you did not read the warnings at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native The setup you have does not support GPU on Windows, you have to use WSL.
